# Possible to add an imported library to target_link_libraries that takes care of include directories too?

Tags: c++, include, cmake

somehow I am struggling with finding out whether it is possible to define an imported library in CMake, specifying target properties (include_directories and library path) and hoping that CMake will append the include directories once I add that project to target_link_libraries in another project.

Let's say I have an imported library in a file called Module-Conf.cmake:

```
add_library(mymodule STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(mymodule PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OUTPUT_DIR}/lib")
set_target_properties(mymodule PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${OUTPUT_DIR}/include")
```

And in a project I add the dependency:

```
include(Module-Conf)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mymodule)
```

Will CMake append the include_directories property to the include path? Right now I cannot see the path so it seems that I have to do it by myself by using get_target_property?

Question: Can I do some CMake magic to automatically append the include to the include directories of another project?

Thanks a lot.
Martin

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The difference between the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property and the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property is transitivity.

Set `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` instead.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements

Answer (score 1):

Starting from CMake 3.11, it's possible to use [target_include_directories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) with IMPORTED targets.

```
add_library(mymodule SHARED IMPORTED)
target_include_directories(mymodule INTERFACE
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>)
```

Another way is [set_property()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html), which also allows using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html).

```
set_property(TARGET mymodule PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>)
```