# cmake: create a new library target which consists of a prebuilt library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to create a custom target in cmake which:

- links a vendor supplied archive
- adds `target_compile_options(... PUBLIC ...)`
- adds `target_include_directories(... PUBLIC ...)`

In this way consumers can link against my new target and have requisite include directories and compile options set.

In boost-build you can use the [`<file>`](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/libraries.html) feature to "wrap" or "alias" a prebuilt library, and add additional "usage requirements" (compiler flags etc) which will be added to all targets using the library.

```
lib foo 
: 
: <file>vendor/library.a
:
: <include>vendor
;
```

- This aliases `vendor/library.a` as a new library `foo`.
- When another target uses `foo` it will also have its include paths updated.
- The code using `foo` will then be able to `#include "foo.h"`, and the file will be found because `vendor` has been added to the include paths.

I'm looking for a way to do the same thing in CMake.

The way I would currently do it would be something along these lines:

```
find_library(LIB_FOO library.a PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/vendor NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

target_link_library       (my_target ${LIB_FOO})
target_include_directories(my_target PRIVATE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/vendor")
```

However, if there are several targets which need to use `foo` then these 3 calls would have be repeated for each of them, which becomes quite onerous.

It would be far easier for consumers of `foo` to have some other target which has

```
target_link_libraries     (foo ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/library.a)
target_compile_options    (foo PUBLIC ...)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ...)
```

**Question:**

- Can I create a **new** library target which consists of a prebuilt library which will allow me to do what I've described?

**Edit in response to comment:**

I have tried to create an `IMPORTED` library (as described [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets)):

```
add_library(foo STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor/library.a)
```

However, when I then try to set include directories I get an error:

```
target_include_directories(foo SYSTEM PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/vendor")
```

Error:

> ```
> CMake Error at vendor/CMakeLists.txt:39 (target_include_directories):
>   Cannot specify include directories for imported target "foo".
> ```

Comment: I guess you need to import a pre-built library, like it's done [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets)

Comment: @user3159253 Thanks! Although how do I then add the `target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ...)` onto my `IMPORTED target`?   I'm getting an error `Cannot specify include directories for imported target "foo".`

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907478/possible-to-add-an-imported-library-to-target-link-libraries-that-takes-care-of) :) Also check this [issue](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15689) So it seems that right now you have to use `set_target_properties(... INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ...)`. Looks ugly, but hopefully works

Comment: Thanks!! If you want to put it into an answer I'll gladly accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to import a pre-built library. [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/Exporting-and-Importing-Targets) is the tutorial how to do it.
2. To make the resulted target "complete" you need to add certain properties to it. Unfortunately this can't be done using usual techniques, because of [this CMake issue](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15689). So you have to set these props manually, like described in [this SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907478/possible-to-add-an-imported-library-to-target-link-libraries-that-takes-care-of)