# "No such file or directory" when linking shared library with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have am trying to link a precompiled `so` file to my executable in cmake. I'm not sure if I am misunderstanding how to use a shared library or not but I assumed that once I compile a shared library, any application can link to it and use it's functions. When compiling the executable, I get this error:

```
logger.h: No such file or directory
 #include "logger.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Here is my cmake file for the executable

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# set PROJECT home directory 
set(PROJECT_HOME "/opt/PROJECT")

# set the project name
project(ClServer)

# add the executable
add_executable(ClServer server.cpp)

add_library(logger SHARED IMPORTED libClLogger.so)

message ("Here")

set_target_properties(logger
PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "#{PROJECT_HOME}/base"
)

target_link_libraries(ClServer
${Logger}
)
```

I've also tried using `find_library` and adding an absolute path to the shared library using `target_link_libraries`, but the same error occurs.

Here is my cmake file for the logger shared library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# set Clamor home directory 
set(PROJECT_HOME "/opt/PROJECT")

# set the project name
project(ClLogger)

# set boost paths
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
if (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)
    set(BOOST_ROOT "${PROJECT_HOME}/ext/Boost/boost_1_76_0")
    set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "${PROJECT_HOME}/ext/Boost/boost_1_76_0/stage/lib")
    set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "${PROJECT_HOME}/ext/Boost/boost_1_76_0")
endif (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)

# provides the linker with the appropriate directories and components
find_package(Boost 1.76.0 COMPONENTS log log_setup thread filesystem system)
if(Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})
  link_directories(${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})
endif()

message (STATUS Boost_LIBRARIES:)
message (STATUS ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
message (STATUS BOOST_INCLUDEDIR:)
message (STATUS ${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})

# add PROJECT source code libraries
add_library(ClLogger SHARED logger.cpp)

# link the appropriate libraries
target_link_libraries(ClLogger
libpthread.so.0
${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)

# redirect binaries to base folder
set_target_properties(ClLogger
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_HOME}/base"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_HOME}/base"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_HOME}/base"
)
```

Comment: You need to add **include directory** which contains the required header (`logger.h`). You could do that either by "generic way", following on of the answers for [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake). Or you could do that via IMPORTED library target which you have, using property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY`, similar to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907478/possible-to-add-an-imported-library-to-target-link-libraries-that-takes-care-of).

Comment: Also note, that in CMake **targets** and **variables** are different things. Expression `${Logger}` dereferences `Logger` **variable** which you have never defined. Instead use `target_link_libraries(ClServer Logger)` for link with the IMPORTED **target**.

Answer (score 0):

To consume a shared library, you need two things. First, shared library file and second public header file. Header file will get used in compilation stage and shared library file in linking stage. Error you are seeing is a compilation failure which says it failed to find header file "logger.h". Use target_include_directories in cmake of your executable to tell cmake where to look for header logger.h.
Additionally if you want cmake to keep watch on logger.h modification, you can add logger.h as source file of your executable.

Answer (score -1):

After a bit of research and testing in my local machine,
i have updated my answer with the simple example tested on eclipse CDT and cmake in WSL2.(should work on any other environment fine ).
the following example should provide an answer to the question.

```
 cmake_test/
 ├── CMakeLists.txt
 ├── build
 ├── cmake_test.cpp
 └── **companyLibrary**
     ├── CMakeLists.txt
     ├── build
     ├── include
     │   └── Company.h
     └── src
         └── Company.cpp
```

from the above project hierarchy companyLibrary is the one which generates the .so (shared Library), which will be used by cmake_test.cpp source file which is at the root level of the project.

***cmake_test/companyLibrary/CMakeLists.txt***

```
 cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

 project (companyLibrary_test)
 set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

 #adding the header <.h> files into the project
 include_directories(include)

 file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

 add_library(testCompany SHARED ${SOURCES})

 install(TARGETS testCompany DESTINATION /usr/lib)
```

this generates the .so file in this example (libtestCompany.so)

```
 sudo make install
```

this will put .so file in /usr/lib folder

now this shared library will be used by the root project cmake_test.cpp file

***cmake_test/CMakeLists.txt***

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (cmake_test)

set ( PROJECT_LINK_LIBS libtestCompany.so )
link_directories( "/usr/lib" )
include_directories( "companyLibrary/include" )

add_executable( libtest cmake_test.cpp )
target_link_libraries( libtest ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} )
```

**add_executable** and **target_link_libraries** should solve the problem
as show above.

full source code availabe [***here***](https://github.com/abhishekkarigar/cmake_examples/tree/main/cmake_test) on ***GitHub***.

hope it helps :)

Comment: This did not work, it produced the same error. Do I need to add something to cmake file that compiles the logger shared library or to the logger header file in order to allow it to be exported? I'm sure I am just missing something small

Comment: target_link_libraries(ClServer PRIVATE logger)

Comment: can you add the above statement and run again, let me know

Comment: This also did not solve it. I added the other cmake file for more context

Comment: @milos miladinov sorry , took more time to come with proper working example,
hope it works as i tested it on my machine .